# Sub Domain Route Not Working

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my `web.php` I have the following route set up.  What I was wanting to know is there something specific that I need to follow to get a sub domain of a sub domain to work?

The domain I am using is blah.blah.domain.tld

**web.php:**

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{blah}.blah.domain.tld'], function (){

    Route::get('', 'DealsFrontEnd@index' );

});
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class DealsFrontEnd extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('front.deals');
    }
}
```

Comment: @Devon I don't seem to be getting anything off the controller

Comment: @Devon I only went off what was in the laravel user guide in terms of using a sub domain.  I am not getting a 404 I am just getting a white page

Comment: The user guide is showing an example of a dynamic sub domain that you can capture, if you want it static, remove the brackets.   If you're not getting a 404, then the route is most likely working and the issue resides else where.   Make use of Laravel's `artisan route:list`.

Comment: could you show us virtual host entry

Comment: @Devon Thanks Devon, I have made use of that and I can now see the url is loading the controller I want however I am still getting a white page.  My deals view is located in resources/views/front are my paths correct?

Comment: @Devon https://www.dropbox.com/s/795c7g6rrlsn5y2/Screenshot%202016-09-15%2017.35.10.png?dl=0

Comment: Yes, that would normally be how you'd represent views/front/deals.blade.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment: Try using a closure for debugging:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{blah}.blah.domain.tld'], function (){

    Route::get('', function() {
        echo "Hello World";
    });

});
```

Make sure you have debug enabled to make use of Laravel's error handling/reporting.

---

As I said in the comments, you shouldn't wrap the subdomain in brackets unless you want it to be dynamic.

`{blah}.blah` means it will capture `anything.blah` and the route variable `$blah` will be equal to `anything`.